# Resizable text, in resizable window

Tags: python, pygame

How do I display the text for resizable window? 
Also, is it possible to have different backgrounds for different circumstances?
For example, I want "game welcoming" to have one background image, and main menu another.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import argparse
import threading, os, sys, time

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("AI Battlehip Game")
FPS = pygame.time.Clock()

red_ = (255,0,0)

def background_image_settings(back_end_image):
    back_end_image_set = pygame.image.load(back_end_image)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,700), HWSURFACE|DOUBLEBUF|RESIZABLE)
    screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(back_end_image_set, (1200,700)), (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    try:                                                    #This function is responsible for making the window resizable and creating the background (in my case it is picture)
        while True:
            pygame.event.pump()
            event = pygame.event.wait()
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.display.quit()
            elif event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
                screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'], HWSURFACE|DOUBLEBUF|RESIZABLE)
                screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(back_end_image_set,event.dict['size']), (0,0))
                pygame.display.flip()
    except:
        pass

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, red_check)    #This function is responsible for making the text colourful and font.   #Have seen it working with TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()        


background_image_settings(r'/Users/user1/Desktop/Project work/images/backgroundimage2.jpg')
```

Comment: edit: text above code... otherwise hard to digest. Also, what did you try before just pasting code? Tell us and we might sail with you and throw a bomb or two on the enemy spot ;p

Comment: @Torxed Oh. Looks like I mis-remembered there, whoops.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I get the question, but do you want to scale text according to the size of the window proportionally? if so, why not use `window_size / desired_scale` on [pygame.font](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.size)? Or use the method ideology in here: https://www.pygame.org/wiki/WindowResizing

Comment: @ZF007 Sure, I am trying to make a text proportionally to the window resolution. In tutorials, teacher used two variables width and height. However in my case, my height and width not constant, and can be changed. So I don't know how to place the text (at which coordinates) and how make it move proportionally to the resolution of window.

Comment: @Torxed I used that ideology with Window Resizing, however, when I wanted to make the program to display the text, and work proportionally to the resolution, I stuck, and couldn't find the method anywhere. Will check how it works with *window_size / desired scale* . Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

`screen.blit()` at a position that is some formula times screen width and height:

for example, in a golf simulator you could use code like this:

```
window.blit(stroke_label, (SCREEN_WIDTH - (.21+.02*math.floor(math.log10(strokes))) * SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT - .985 * SCREEN_HEIGHT))
```